# Add dropshadow on specific scroll position

Tags: javascript

I've coded a function that gives an element a dropshadow when there is a specific scroll position. So I want to give a dropshadow to the first element when the scroll position is greater than 40. When you keep scrolling, the second element will get a dropshadow when the scroll position is greater than 90. However, this works for the first element but not for the second: even when the scroll offset is greater than 90, still the first element has the drop shadow.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
       var scroll = this.scrollY;
       if (scroll > 40)
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="0px 0px 45px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)";
            document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow=""}
       else if (scroll > 90)
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="";
            document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow="0px 0px 45px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)"}
       else 
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="";
             document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow=""}
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scroll offset is greater than 90, the program will still enter into the first case as (obviously) a number greater than 90 must be greater than 40 as well.

That will cause the `else if` part to be skipped, and the first element will be focused always.

To solve this problem, you can either:

- Move the `> 90` part *before* the `> 40`. That way, if it's greater than 90, it will enter into that case, and skip the others:

  ```
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
       var scroll = this.scrollY;
       if (scroll > 90)
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="";
            document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow="0px 0px 45px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)"}
       else if (scroll > 40)
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="0px 0px 45px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)";
            document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow=""}
       else 
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="";
             document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow=""}
  })
  ```
- Add another condition to check whether it's big enough for the second element:

  ```
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
       var scroll = this.scrollY;
       if (scroll > 40 && scroll <= 90)
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="0px 0px 45px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)";
            document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow=""}
       else if (scroll > 90)
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="";
            document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow="0px 0px 45px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)"}
       else 
            {document.getElementById("Gegevens").style.boxShadow="";
             document.getElementById("Uren").style.boxShadow=""}
  })
  ```